# How do I spawn a BASH command in expect?

Tags: bash, shell-script, expect

I have an expect script, and want to spawn a BASH command for it to provide input to. When I use the following syntax:

```
spawn /bin/bash docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_initpki`
```

or:

```
spawn docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_initpki
```

I get the following error:

```
bad flag "-it": must be -glob, -regexp, -exact, -notransfer, -nocase, -i, -
indices, -iread, -timestamp, -timeout, -nobrace, or --
    while executing
"expect {
   spawn (/bin/bash) docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn 
ovpn_initpki
   "Enter PEM pass phrase:"   {send "DefPEMVPNPassPhra..."
    (file "addcontainer.exp" line 7)
```

How do I tell expect to spawn a BASH command?

Comment: Don't put the `spawn` command inside `expect`, do what I suggested [in your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/422515/4667)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to access environment variables in TCL (`expect` is a TCL interpreter) is `$env(VARNAME)`, so:

```
spawn docker run -v $env(OVPN_DATA):/etc/openvpn --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_initpki
```

If you want to run a shell to interpret some shell code, you'd run `sh -c the-code` (or `bash -c` though there's nothing `bash`-specific in that shell code here). That's what the `system()` function of most languages to.

```
spawn sh -c {
  docker run -v "$OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn" --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_initpki
}
```

`{...}` are the strong quotes in TCL. I also added the missing quotes around the shell variable expansion, as otherwise it would be more `zsh`/`rc`/`fish` syntax than `sh` syntax.

Also, you'd `spawn` before any `expect ...` statement. The `spawn` command is to launch the command you want to interact with, the `expect ...` statement is to wait for specific output from that command.

In your code above, you're not running `spawn` at all, that  `spawn` inside the `expect` argument is take as a pattern to look for in the output of an earlier spawned command if any, or from stdin if not.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
spawn /bin/bash
send "docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn  ovpn_initpki"
```

Comment: You will need to escape the `$` as tcl will expand this within `""`. Or you can replace the double quotes by `{}` quotes.

Comment: It's also possible that the quoting can be dropped, and just the -c will be enough to load up bash.  Or maybe just quote "docker", though that may not take care of how tcl will handle the variable definitions within the expect file.

Comment: `bad flag "-c": must be -glob, -regexp, -exact, -notransfer, -nocase, -i, -indices, -iread, -timestamp, -timeout, -nobrace, or --`

Comment: The error that you are reporting is from expect.  I updated my answer

Comment: @JohnW.Gill Not sure what's going on. No errors when I use that code but the container shows many errors saying that the configuration files don't exist (that are created with that input). I'll investigate further.

Comment: The bash shell being instantiated in that way is likely bare bones, with only the default configurations in place. (think /etc/profile, etc.)  If the configuration files aren't being found, some things may need to be added to the /bin/bash part of the spawn command to find the expected system variables and config files.

Answer (score 0):

The output suggests that `spawn` doesn't stop interpreting flags when it encounters a command name.

A common convention is to use `--` as a separator between options for a command (which it should parse and interpret), and arguments to things it needs to call (which it should ignore and pass on).

The `spawn` output lists `--` as one of the possible options, which suggests that it follows that convention. Try specifying it?

```
spawn /bin/bash -- -c "docker run ..."
```

Comment: the `--` probably shouldn't be placed after `bash` and before `bash` flags ...