# sed error on expect script

Tags: sed, expect

I am trying to use a simple sed command inside with a expect script

```
spawn sed -n '/0032ff00/,/clogoff/p' /tmp/file.tmp > /tmp/file.tmp1
```

I get an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I also tried with replacing the `''` with `{}`

```
spawn sed -n {/0032ff00/,/clogoff/p} /tmp/file.tmp > /tmp/file.tmp1
```

Then I get:

```
sed: can't read >: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /tmp/file.tmp1: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I spawn a BASH command in expect?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422583/how-do-i-spawn-a-bash-command-in-expect)

Comment: With particular reference to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516097/100397)